# Group COL2 based on COL1, then count total number of COL2

Tags: awk

I have a file below.

```
BDNF    FTO
BDNF    GNPDA2
BDNF    MAP2K5
BDNF    MC4R
BDNF    MTCH2
BDNF    NEGR1
BDNF    NGFR
BDNF    PPARG
BDNF    SORT1
CDK4    CDKN2A
CDK4    MDM2
CDK4    PPARG
```

Would like to group COL2 based on COL1, and generates a COL3 by counting the number of entities in COL2.

The output should be:

```
BDNF    FTO, GNPDA2, MAP2K5, MC4R, MTCH2, NEGR1, NGFR, PPARG, SORT1 9
CDK4    CDKN2A, MDM2, PPARG 3
```

My code is:

```
awk '{ A[$1]=A[$1]", "$2 } END { for(X in A) print X,substr(A[X],2) }' filename
```

I was able to group COL2 based on COL1, but unable to generate COL3, which contains the count of COL2.

Could someone please correct help to improve the code?

Comment: Is the input grouped by the first column, as in the sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To generate the values) the straightforward way is simply to count (corrected)

```
awk '{A[$1]=A[$1]", "$2;N[$1]++} END{for(X in A)print X,substr(A[X],2),N[X]}'
# if ++N[$1] if you prefer; if the result is ignored these are the same
```

but as long as there are never commas in the $2 inputs (which is nearly necessary for your outputs to be unambiguously interpretable anyway) you can use a silly trick

```
awk '{A[$1]=A[$1]", "$2} END{for(X in A)print X,substr(A[X],2),gsub(/,/,",",A[X])}'
# the gsub call changes each comma in A[X] to comma (no actual change) 
# but returns an integer of the number of 'changes' made
```

However if you want the output separation between $1 and list-of-$2 to be a tab and between list-of-$2 and count-of-$2 to be a space, as the format you posted looks like, you need to either change to `print $1"\t"...,...` or pre-set `OFS="\t"` and then `print $1,..." "...`

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, the first AWK code doesn't work. Seems to have some syntax errors. Meanwhile, the second one works flawlessly.

Comment: austin7923: one character that I copied wrong -- the error message does you point at the error which is pretty obvious, but fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read all of your input into memory for this, as you're currently doing by creating an array, which can be important for efficiency or just ability to work at all if your input is large. Just print the data every time the key value changes, e.g. using any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $1!=prev { if (NR>1) print prev, vals, cnt; vals=sep=cnt=""; prev=$1 }
    { vals=vals sep $2; sep=", "; cnt++ }
    END { print prev, vals, cnt }
' file
BDNF    FTO, GNPDA2, MAP2K5, MC4R, MTCH2, NEGR1, NGFR, PPARG, SORT1     9
CDK4    99CDKN2A, MDM2, PPARG   3
```

This will output the key (`$1`) values in the same order they appeared in the input, unlike the `for(X in A)` in your question which will produce the output in some undefined order.

It requires your input to be grouped by the key field so if your input isn't already grouped on the key field then just run `sort` on it before piping to `awk`.